# Activate a textbox if I select a particular option in drop down box in html without using java

Tags: html

I have to make a webpage in HTML, and strictly not use Java .

```
Do You wish to enter Scientific Name:<select name="snc">
<option value="n" selected>No</option>
<option value="y">Yes</option>
</select>
Scientific Name: <input type="text" name="sn"><br>
```

All solutions i found for this had java used.

Is it possible for me to make the "Scientific Name" Box come only if the option is "Yes" 
Remember java in any form is not allowed.

If possible, please tell me how.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript? Either way, HTML is not interactive on it's own. You're going to have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I mean Javascript and Java applets.

Comment: @AkhilKulkarni any particular reason why you can't use JavaScript?

Comment: I am doing an internship in a high performance computing organisation. This page is a small part of what I am doing, here I must make the UI to send data to a python program which inturn fetches data from remote distributed databases, integrates them, and displays it. 
My boss told me not to use java applet etc because they are very heavy, and slower computers and 2mb ram processors will not be able to handle them. I don't know how much of it is true, i'm a newbie to all this, but I must do what the boss says :)

Comment: @Dale , please add your comment as an Answer, so I can accept it. Thank you both for your time.

Comment: JavaScript is NOT Java, JavaScript runs in the browser and is lightning fast (for operations such as enabling an input)

Comment: I am already implementing the validation to handle it. The web page just looks neater if the boxes are hidden when not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make a input tag change it's visibility without some script function.

It is possible to validate your input via your server side scripts.

If you need more information, please ask.